# kill switch proxy как реализовать?

Tags: ip, proxy, firewall

Нужно реализовать отключение интернета при сбоях в работе с прокси (падением софта или самого прокси сервера)
Аптайм интернет соединения не важен главное не спалить хостовый айпи
Слышал что можно настроить это в Стоковом фаерволе винды подскажите как?
Машина на вмвейр[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не видно, где автор пытался решить его самостоятельно (найти конкретику по firewall, например) перед тем, как задать вопрос.

Comment: Добавил скриншот как я добавил правило

Comment: Кирилл, "Слышал что можно настроить это в Стоковом фаерволе винды подскажите как?" - неверно поставленный тут вопрос. Правильный путь: открыть документацию и посмотреть там. Тогда правильный вопрос должен быть хотя бы: "слышал, открыл документацию, вот этот кусок вижу а вот этого не вижу. Где это смотреть (или как делать)?"